# Latex Font Warning after updating to TeXlive 2016

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ieeetran

After updating to TeXlive 2016, I get the following font warning in the `IEEEtran.cls` file:

```
./IEEEtran.cls:458: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/m/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 458.

./IEEEtran.cls:1039: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/ptm/m/n' instead on input line 1039.

./IEEEtran.cls:1039: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/m/it' undefined(Font) using `TU/ptm/m/n' instead on input line 1039.

./IEEEtran.cls:1039: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/bx/it' undefined(Font) using `TU/ptm/bx/n' instead on input line 1039.

[no file]: LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted. : (Log parsing issues. Disregard unless something else is wrong.)
```

Before the update, everything was fine, not a single warning in place.

Typesetting wise, if I include `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (I'm using xelatex) the template seems correct and the pdf passes the IEEE pdfExpress test. However it is a few lines shorter, and I do not understand how and why. Mostly I am asking out of curiosity as well as fixing those warnings that get to my nerves.

Comment: The class isn't really meant for xelatex. It setups all fonts with (pdf)latex names like ptm etc. And now that the latex format has been better adapted to xelatex and uses the TU encoding by default it shows.

Comment: Indeed that is true. What do you suggest though? Do you reckon there is a way to keep using XeLaTeX or should I just run it on pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Why do you want to use xelatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can imagine someone who uses latex to typeset Chinese documents every day would prefer his toolchain to default to xelatex.

Comment: @alick I can imagine a number of reasons why *someone* would want to use xelatex, but I wanted to know if *phen3x* has a reason.

Comment: I know it's long overdue but the post was lost in the cracks. The main reason is that I have occasionally experienced problems with IEEE submissions when submitting pdflatex documents (even though pdflatex is the proper engine for IEEE templates). Xelatex works like a charm though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using

```
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
```

would restore the previous OT1 (7-bit) default and give you the version that you had previously.

Note that using T1 encoding with xetex is not recommended as hyphenation will, in general, be incorrect in that case. (OT1 only allows hyphenation in words that use ascii, where the encoding matches Unicode)